# How to check mutliple assert on a page?

Tags: selenium, xpath, assert

In my screen i have 2 text "FN1394538779762 LN1394538779762" and i need to check this text using single xpath.

```
K1394538779762 L1394538779762
```

I tried something like below, but that doesn't work. Can you help me how to do that?

```
Common.assertTextOnPage(driver, "K" + uniqueID "L" + uniqueID);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Common.assertTextOnPage(driver, "K" + uniqueID + " L" + uniqueID);
```

Instead of:

```
Common.assertTextOnPage(driver, "K" + uniqueID "L" + uniqueID);
```